# change text direction in excel using VB code

Tags: excel, vb6

I want to change text direction in a cell from left-to-right to right-to-left using vb code.
Can any one guide me to do that?
thanks.

Comment: hat have you tried? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It is easy, you just need to create a Function in Excel with the following code:

Function Reversestr(str As String) As String
Reversestr = StrReverse(Trim(str))
End Function

Then just use the function inside a cell like

=Reversestr("Text you want to reverse")